# Using reduce to remap an array with child arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm struggling to work out how to remap the below array.

I have tried to use the reduce function built into JS but to no avail.

The furthest I have got it creating the function:

```
var comb = []
var setEle = []
var setEle = []
input.forEach(a => {
  a.productVariations.forEach(element => {
    if (comb.indexOf(element.variationName) === -1) {
      comb.push(element.variationName)

      let group = element.variationOptions.reduce((r, a) => {
        r['variationName'] = element.variationName
        r['variationOptions'] = [...(r[a.name] || []), a]

        return r
      }, {})

      group['linked'] = []
      setEle.push(group)
    }
  })

})
```

How do I remap the array as below and get my reduce function working?

```
var input = [
  {
    companyName: 'ABC',
    productVariations: [
      {
        variationName: 'Colour',
        variationOptions: [
          {
            name: 'Blue'
          },
          {
            name: 'Red'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        variationName: 'Pattern',
        variationOptions: [
          {
            name: 'Bold'
          },
          {
            name: 'Spotted'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    companyName: 'BBC',
    productVariations: [
      {
        variationName: 'Colour',
        variationOptions: [
          {
            name: 'Blue'
          },
          {
            name: 'Red'
          },
          {
            name: 'Purple '
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like the output to look like this:

```
var output = [
  {
    variationName: 'Colour',
    variationOptions: [
      {
        name: 'Blue'
      },
      {
        name: 'Purple'
      },
      {
        name: 'Red'
      },
    ],
    linked: [
      {
        companyName: 'BBC'
      },
      {
        companyName: 'ABC'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    variationName: 'Pattern',
    variationOptions: [
      {
        name: 'Bold'
      },
      {
        name: 'Spotted'
      },
    ],
    linked: [
      {
        companyName: 'ABC',
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The output array, groups the `variationOptions` by `variationName` and adds the relevant companyName to the `linked` child array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if not particular about reduce, use `forEach` and build the object with values `companyNames` and `variationOptions` as `Set` so that we will have unique items.
From above object, again build the array using `map` over above sets.

```js
const converge = (arr) => {
  const res = {};
  arr.forEach(({ companyName, productVariations }) => {
    productVariations.forEach(({ variationName, variationOptions }) => {
      if (!res[variationName]) {
        res[variationName] = { options: new Set(), links: new Set() };
      }
      res[variationName].links.add(companyName);
      variationOptions.forEach(({ name }) =>
        res[variationName].options.add(name)
      );
    });
  });
  return Object.entries(res).map(([variationName, {options, links}]) => ({
    variationName,
    variationOptions: [...options].map((name) => ({ name })),
    linked: [...links].map((companyName) => ({ companyName })),
  }));
};

var input = [
  {
    companyName: "ABC",
    productVariations: [
      {
        variationName: "Colour",
        variationOptions: [
          {
            name: "Blue",
          },
          {
            name: "Red",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        variationName: "Pattern",
        variationOptions: [
          {
            name: "Bold",
          },
          {
            name: "Spotted",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    companyName: "BBC",
    productVariations: [
      {
        variationName: "Colour",
        variationOptions: [
          {
            name: "Blue",
          },
          {
            name: "Red",
          },
          {
            name: "Purple ",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

console.log(converge(input));
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```js
const input = [
  {
    companyName: 'ABC',
    productVariations: [
      {
        variationName: 'Colour',
        variationOptions: [{ name: 'Blue' }, { name: 'Red' }],
      },
      {
        variationName: 'Pattern',
        variationOptions: [{ name: 'Bold' }, { name: 'Spotted' }],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    companyName: 'BBC',
    productVariations: [
      {
        variationName: 'Colour',
        variationOptions: [{ name: 'Blue' }, { name: 'Red' }, { name: 'Purple' }],
      },
    ],
  },
];

const output = input.reduce((currentOutput, company) => {
  company.productVariations.forEach(variation => {
    const variationIndex = currentOutput.findIndex(
      outputVariation => variation.variationName === outputVariation.variationName,
    );
    if (variationIndex === -1) {
      // if this variation does not yet exist in the output create it
      currentOutput.push({
        variationName: variation.variationName,
        variationOptions: variation.variationOptions,
        linked: [{ companyName: company.companyName }],
      });
    } else {
      // if it already exists go through all options and add the ones that are not there yet
      variation.variationOptions.forEach(variationOption => {
        if (
          !currentOutput[variationIndex].variationOptions.some(
            outputVariationOption => variationOption.name === outputVariationOption.name,
          )
        ) {
          currentOutput[variationIndex].variationOptions.push(variationOption);
        }
      });
      // link the company
      currentOutput[variationIndex].linked.push({ companyName: company.companyName });
    }
  });
  return currentOutput;
}, []);

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(output, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="output" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help

```
    const variations= input.flatMap(obj => obj.productVariations.map(x => ({...x, linked:[{companyName: obj.companyName}]})))
    const final = variations.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        const obj = acc.find(x => x.variationName === curr.variationName)
        if(obj) {
            const uniqueOptions = [...new Set([...curr.variationOptions, ...obj.variationOptions].map(x => x.name))]
            obj.variationOptions = uniqueOptions.map(x => ({name: x}));
            obj.linked.push(...curr.linked)
        }
        else {
            acc.push(curr)
        }
        return acc;
    } ,[])
```